# Mongoose - setting virtuals via return on callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, mongoose

I see similar questions posted all over stackoverflow, but can't seem to find a satisfactory answer.

I'm using MongooseJS as my ODM and I'm trying to set up virtual getters than query, analyze and return information from a different collection.

Unfortunately, (because of nodejs asynchronous nature) I can't return information from within a callback function. Is there an easy way of going about this?

Here's my code:

```
UserSchema.virtual('info').get(function () {

    var data = {
        a: 0,
        b: 0
    };

    OtherSchema.find({}, function (err, results) {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            if (result.open) {
                data.a += 1
            } else {
                data.b += 1
            }
        });
        return data; //return this information
    })

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is another solution. Make your virtual a function that takes a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a callback function into your virtual method, like so:

```
UserSchema.virtual('info').get(function (cb) {

var data = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
};

OtherSchema.find({}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        // pass the error back to the calling function if it exists
        return cb(err);
    }

    results.forEach(function(result) {
        if(result.open) { data.a+=1 }
            else{data.b+=1}
    });

    // pass null back for the error and data back as the response
    cb(null, data);
});

});
```

Then to call the function you would do (excuse my syntax on calling the virtual method. Not 100% sure how that works in Mongoose):

```
UserSchema.info(function(err, data) {
    // check if there was an error
    // if not then do whatever with the data
}
```